# Minimum order for free shipping with multicurrencies

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm managing a woo commerce site with two different currencies (euro and yen): how can I make convertible the minimum amount of order for free shipping? For now, when I visit the website from Japan and I see the yen prices, the free shipping is allowed over 50 yen (because the break point is 50€ for Europe market) but I need make it allowed over 6500 yen (50 euro). How can I do? Booster for woo commerce (the plugin that I'm using for multi currency) hasn't this feature.
I tried both with woocommerce multicurrency setting and Booster free version settings.

Comment: Maybe research over on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Nope, i have already looked for but i found nothing of interesting about that problem, unfortunately

Comment: Still, this is probably off-topic for SO. If you have a specific question about some code you should show a [mcve] and describe what results you get. Otherwise, the best place for research and maybe a question is on that other SE.